# Algorithm for induced subforest of a tree

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, trees, graph-isomorphism

I'm currently working on my Master's thesis and my cause would be helped a lot of there existed an (efficient) algorithm for deciding if a given tree $G$ contains a forest $H$ as an induced subforest.
Does anyone know if such an algorithm already exists?

There do already exist (very) efficient algorithms for deciding this if $H$ is a tree.

(See for example: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0196677499910441 )

Comment: This is a NP-complete problem https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/46122/isomorphic-subforest-problem

Comment: The link you provided isn't the same problem.

Comment: @MathieuRundström Ok, we talk here about induced subgraphs, but it does not change anything to the reduction from 3-partition given in Garey&johnson (you just need to add 3 more vertices per branch)